# Number of devices connecting to wireless router are limiting

Tags: router, wireless-networking

I have NETGEAR DGN2200 wireless router in my home. I have configured it to support any device can connect to it. But after 15 devices, no other device can connect to the router. Please suggest what could be the issue and the solution?

Comment: All APs have a limit to the number of active associations. You've apparently found the limit of yours.

Comment: What error do you get on the 16th device that you are trying to associate? Maybe is DHCP problem, you can check lease time or dhcp pool, or as Ricky said you are on the limit of the device that I think is on 20-25 but depends on devices. If you reached the limit of your device you have to add a new AP

Comment: Sadly, your consumer Netgear wifi ap is off-topic here.  [su] is a better place to ask home networking questions

Comment: @emirjonb I am not getting any error. It tries to connect and shows connecting forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because your router has a 15 device limit to the devices that can connect. This may not be changeable but you can try to go to your default gateway. To find the IP of your default gateway go to the command prompt and run the command ipconfig (linux ifconfig) and get the ip address next to the default gateway and paste it into your browser. Then you should be able to find a setting that allows you to specify a limit of devices on your network in your router configuration page if you can configure it. Then just change the number to the devices you need to connect and then scroll to the bottom of the page press the button that should say something like save configuration of save settings and you should be good to go.

Comment: I couldn't find a setting to configure the number of devices in the router configuration page.

Comment: Oh then your router can probably not handle more then fifteen devices I would suggest upgrading your router